# Basic Rails pattern for associating models to parents (nesting?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, data-modeling, restful-url

I'm new to Rails and trying to understand how we build 'complex' Models (and their associations) using tools available to us in Rails. Quickly imagine the following example scenario: `Users` are a member of ONE racing `Team`. Users can create `Cars` and `Schedules`. These Cars have `Drivers`, `Fuel` levels, `Engines` and `Wheels`. These `Wheels` have `Tires`, `Hubs` and `MilesDriven`. You get the idea...

Given all the warnings about nesting only 1 level deep...I *still* struggle with how to be RESTful and Rails-y and present a UI that allows a user to build a `Car` with `Tires`.

I know we have a `Session` & `Cookie` at our disposal as well as Hidden fields. So user logs in...and is routed to their team page `teams(current_user.team_id)`. Then they want to create a `Car`. this routes to `new_team_car_path(current_user.team_id)` where they can build a car... now I want to add a Wheel to this car... so does that route to `new_team_car_wheel_path(current_user.team_id, car_id)`, etc, etc...?  I think not...  But, what is the Rail-y way?

Also, as everything built will be associated, ultimately, to a team (and user) is it best to 'carry' the `team_id` and/or `user_id` association all the way down to the `Tire` *or* is it reasonable to query the `Team` by following the associations up the hierarchy at runtime?

I'm sure this is basic stuff but newbness has me confused about how to best approach it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no single answer to this question. You mentioned using session variables and hidden fields -- those are viable approaches, and the decision will have to be based on the specific requirements. The fact that you are struggling to find the best answer is a good sign, in that it shows you're willing to consider alternatives.

In this case you have a leg up because you don't need to pass in the user information or its associations in the URL, since your authorization code already makes it available in th controller. So I'd drop the user and team id from your params and access them from `current_user`:

# GET /cars/:car_id/wheels/new

```
def new
  @car = Car.find(params[:car_id])
  @wheel = @car.wheels.build
end
```

and

# POST /cars/:car_id/wheels

```
def create
  @user = current_user
  @team = @user.team
  @car = Car.find(params[:car_id]
  @wheel = @car.wheels.build(params[:car][:wheel])
  ...
end
```

The only problem is if you need to allow a user to access another user's `Car`. In that case a hidden form field (or a drop down menu) to select the user should work. Conversely, you may need an authorization check to prevent users from accessing each other's `Car'

Comment: ok. Thanks! so, just to clarify...you think it's worthwhile to embed the `user` *and* `team` into the `car` (or `wheel`, or whatever deeply nested resource)? As opposed to walking the `belongs_to` chain back up to find the `user` or `team` when or as you need them?!? And if so is this for optimization reasons? so you aren't constantly querying the DB? Or..??

Comment: In this particular situation you already have paid the performance cost of finding the user, because Devise (or whatever) does that on every request. So I'm saying you *don't* need to nest the resources, as there is a built-in way of detecting `user` and its associations.